# How to resolve Errno::ECONNREFUSED in UsersController#create error in ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, ruby-on-rails-4

Can anybody help me to resolve this following error.I am trying to send an email but it failed to send and throws some error.

Error:

Errno::ECONNREFUSED in UsersController#create
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'

My code snippets are given below.

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Send email to your friend</h1>
<%= form_for @user,:url => {:action => 'create'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field:name,placeholder:"Enter your name" %><br>
    <%= f.email_field:email,placeholder:"Enter your email" %><br>
    <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

views/users/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Successfully registered</h1>
```

views/users/success.html.erb

```
<h1>Email sent successfully</h1>
```

controller/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user=User.new
  end
  def create
    @user=User.new(users_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      redirect_to :action => 'success'
    else
      render :'index'
    end
  end
  def new

  end
  def success

  end
  private
  def users_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
  end
end
```

views/user_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb

```
<%= @user.name%>
<h1>Thank you for registering</h1>
Click <%= link_to "here",users_new_path %>
```

mailer/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default :from => "w5call.w5rtc@gmail.com"
  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user=user
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")
  end
end
```

config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => "w5call.w5rtc@gmail.com",
    :password             => "w5rtc123@",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

endActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp


  end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root 'users#index'
  post "users/create" => "users#create"
 get "users/success" => "users#success"
  get "users/new" => "users#new"
end
```

Actually i was referring this [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3?view=asciicast).I am using rails-4 and ruby 1.9.3.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Check your action_mailer setup for Google. May be you missed domain. E.g. our production setup includes next settings: domain (example@gmail.com), user_name (example), password.